# Get opencmis documents by query with all properties without content stream

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

At the moment I'm getting Alfresco documents by queries like that:

```
select cmis:objectId from cmis:document ...
```

then I get the document itself by the following code:

```
String objectId = qresult.getPropertyValueByQueryName("d.cmis:objectId");
Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(objectId));
```

The problem is that when I get the document like that it seems to transfer the whole contentStream for every document which is not needed in my use-case.

Then I tried to get all properties by changing the query to:

```
select * from cmis:document
```

but this returns only the properties of the document aspect (cmis:name, ...).
Is it possible to get all properties of the document without having to add all aspect with a "join" to the query?

Or is there another way to get documents with all properties but without the contentstream?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`getObject()` does not transfer the content stream, only metadata.
You can control what is fetched from the repository with an [Operation Context](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/operation-context/index.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right the contentstream is not send with the document. It is received when getContentStream is called. My mistake.
Nevertheless getting all properties by query seems to be a lot faster than getting the ObjectId only, then get the document. Is there a way to get the properties of other aspects by query without having to join the other aspects? "select *" does only query the cmis properties but not the cutom properties of custom aspects.

Comment: No, you must do the joins if you want the properties of aspects.